# Higher order vector calculus identities

Tags: vector-analysis

The wikipedia page https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Vector_calculus_identities has vector calculus differentiation identities up to third order. Do higher order identities, in particular for fourth order derivatives, exist somewhere?

Comment: Given an order $n$ identity in which a vector field $\bf A$ is differentiated $n$ times, one can produce an identity in which a vector field is differentiated $n + 1$ times by replacing $\bf A$ with $\text{curl } {\bf B}$.

Comment: Cheers! I hope this will help me.

Comment: In particular I am interested in various identities involving the Laplacian of the Laplacian $\nabla^2 (\nabla^2 u)$.

Comment: In that case, it would be useful for you to mention that in your original question. Of course, one can produce various identities by concatenating identities for the Laplacian. Are you content with these, or are you looking for an identity that cannot, in some sense, be deduced from such identities?

Comment: Yeah, I need 'more information' than what is already contained in the Wikipedia list. I keep going in eternal ever more complicated circles, and producing trivial statements such as 0 = 0. In particular, would be great if i was able to write $u\nabla^2 (\nabla^2 u^2) = \nabla^2(\ldots)$ where we know $\nabla^2 u = 0$.

Comment: So, in particular, you want to produce an equation nonobviously equivalent to $\nabla^2 u = 0$?